# Configuring an App in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, upload, app-store-connect, configure

I want to start to configure my app in iTunes Connect before distribute it in App Store.

I have **Admin** role in my company account, which is **correctly signed** into the Apple Developer Program.

When I go to iTunes Connect, it seems that I would have to see the following page:

[image]

However, when I go to iTunes Connect I don't see that page, I see the following one:

[image]

My question is, **why don't I see the another page?** and...**how can I start to configure the app in iTunes Connect from the first page?**

Thanks a lot, waiting for you help

Answer (score 0):

Do you go to the correct URL http://itunesconnect.apple.com/ ?
I just checked and it works. But sometimes the service becomes temporary unavailable.

Comment: Yes, I go to that link, it asks the apple id + password and then it redirects to me to the page I uploaded (Start to use iTunes Connect page)... :(

Comment: Is your account active?

Answer (score 0):

this is happened because  the id you are using for iTunes connect  for managing app do not have developer account it only happened when the Apple id do not registered as developer

Comment: And how can I create a developer account with this Apple Id? is it free?

Comment: no its not free you must have to registered with iOS development Program which approx charge you 379 AED and it need  a new id which is  not registered with apple iTunes account. if it  help you  so accept the answer thanks regards